# How are photonic crystals different from normal cloth?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, material-science

Beginner here. I recently heard from a graduate level friend of mine, who works on photonic crystals, that they are basically substances that allow only a certain band of wavelengths to to be emitted. But I thought even our clothes (or any other thing for that matter) also emit a certain wavelength, which is related to the perceived color of that thing.

So my question is, how are photonic crystals special (or different from normal matter)?

Comment: It is a question rather on "What are photonic crystals"

Comment: @jaromrax, probably. But I do mention what I think I know about them